# Upload Data to Alamofire Using the Usual Way like Posting other data

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

```
    let parameters = [
        "profile_picture" : "\(profilePictureData)",
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, UPDATE_PROFILE_PICTURE_URL + "token=\(userToken)", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: AUTHENTICATION_HEADER).response { (request, response, data, errorType) -> Void in

        if(data != nil) {
            let responseStr:NSString = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print(responseStr);

            let resultObject: APIResults = APIResults(JSONDecoder(data!));
            let responseCode: Int = Int(resultObject.code!)!;

            if(responseCode == 200) {
                succeeded = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

So far here is my code, I am trying to post my profilePictureData which is a `NSData` to server just like how I would normally send Strings or Int. I put the profilePictureData to the body parameter. This always fail and the server returns error.

How should I send my Image Data to server?

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a model. Just edit it accordingly.

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST,
        URLString: "https://example.com/api/v1/users/\(user_id)/profile_pic.json?auth_token=\(auth_token)",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "avatar", fileName: "avatar_img.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
                case .Success (let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { request, response, data, error in

                    // Do whatever 

                    } 
                case .Failure (let encodingError):
                    //Realistically, I don't expect this to ever trigger, but I guess if the user uses some very weird image format...
            }

        })
```

Comment: Hi, where should I put my header authorization? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I have found the header parameter. Thanks for the help